# how to exclude .sql from a build in VS2010?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I decided to include some SQL Scripts into VS2010 for ease of editing / access.  However, I'm getting a bunch of errors now such as 
"SQL80001: Incorrect syntax near '8'.  Expecting '(', or SELECT."

I don't expect VS to understand the file.  It isn't SQL Server compliant, it's a file that is for another database vendor that have a few minor SQL syntax variations away from the norm (data types, etc).

In any case, I *thought* that **Build Action: None** (a property on the file) would ensure that the compiler didn't touch the file.

Looks like VS has an exception to the rule for files with .sql.  Is there a way to turn this feature off?

Comment: I checked this and is working fine. Can you give more info about the contents of .sql file.

Comment: Maybe Exclude it from Project?

Comment: Maybe use a different file extension? As far as editing goes, VS will assume it is T-SQL (for SQL Server) and base the syntax highlighting on that, which will be wrong if the file is not T-SQL.

Comment: @Sandeep G B:  try some DML such as create table abc(a int not null, b CHAR(8) NOT NULL, ...   Please let me know what happens on you PC.  Over here, files with run of the mill SQL Select or insert statements work.

Comment: @Adam Ralph: thanks.  It pains me to do it because I'm so used to seeing .sql, but it works.

Comment: so... is there a way to turn this off?  We aren't going to be using SQL Server any time soon.

Comment: @sgtz, I tried CREATE, SELECT, INSERT --- scripted out from SQL database. Adding all these files works just fine. FYI, I am using VS 2010 Ultimate.

Comment: @sgtz - I've added my suggestion as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe use a different file extension? As far as editing goes, VS will assume it is T-SQL (for SQL Server) and base the syntax highlighting on that, which will be wrong if the file is not T-SQL.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use **Build Action: Content** option for SQL files

Comment: I looked that up Content http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(%22FILE+PROPERTIES.BUILDACTION%22);k(%22FILE+PROPERTIES%22);k(VS.PROPERTIES);k(VS.SOLUTIONEXPLORER.VSPOLICY);k(VS.SOLUTIONEXPLORER.SELECTION);k(VS.SOLUTIONEXPLORER);k(VS.SOLUTIONEXPLORER.SOLUTIONS);k(SOLUTIONITEMSPROJECT);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22.NETFRAMEWORK%2cVERSION%3dV4.0%22)&rd=true  .  "The file is not compiled, but is included in the Content output group".  That doesn't mean that the file will end up in a distribution does it?  Do not copy will stop this right?

Comment: actually, sorry to say this, but the content option fails as well.  Files with SQL Selects are fine.  Files with DML fail.